# Preload with order_by from another table with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an issue with the order of some preloads.

Basically I have a structure like: `Restaurant > FoodItem > OptionGroup`.
An `OptionGroup` is associated to a `Restaurant`, and can be associated to a `FoodItem` (table with many_to_many `FoodItemOptionGroup`).

In the `food_item.ex` I have the following:

```
many_to_many(
  :option_groups,
  OptionGroup,
  join_through: FoodItemOptionGroup,
  on_delete: :delete_all
)
```

I allow the front end to query the API with the preloads they need, so they can do something like: `?include=food_item.option_groups`. The function iterate and create a preload structure. This is the core part:

```
is_atom(value) ->
    case value do
      :food_items ->
        [{:food_items, from(p in FoodItem, order_by: [p.id])}]

      :option_groups ->
        [{:option_groups, from(og in OptionGroup, order_by: og.id)}]

      :food_extras ->
        [{:food_extras, from(fe in FoodExtra, order_by: fe.id)}]
    end
```

Recently I've implement an `row_weight` that allows me to order by it's value. On `FoodItem` it was simple, just add order_by and it's done. On `OptionGroups`, it's been complicated. Because the `row_weight` is on the association many_to_many `FoodItemOptionGroup`, the preload doesn't work properly.

```
is_atom(value) ->
    case value do
      :food_items ->
        [{:food_items, from(p in FoodItem, order_by: [p.row_weight, p.id])}]

      :option_groups ->
        [
          {
            :option_groups,

            OptionGroup
            |> join(
              :inner,
              [og],
              fiog in Ketchup.FoodItemOptionGroup,
              og.id == fiog.option_group_id
            )
            |> order_by([og, fiog], [fiog.row_weight, og.id])
          }
        ]

      :food_extras ->
        [{:food_extras, from(fe in FoodExtra, order_by: fe.id)}]
    end
```

This will result in multiple `option_groups` being duplicated by the number of associations they are to other `food_items`. It seams that preload pick only the right ones, for example `Temperature` and `Spice` and also take all the other `Temperature` and `Spice` (they share the same `id` because are the some) of other `food_items`.

There was a possible solution to use `group_by`, because I think it doesn't affect the output `OptionGroup`.

```
OptionGroup 
|> join(:inner, [og], fiog in Ketchup.FoodItemOptionGroup, og.id == fiog.option_group_id) 
|> order_by([og, fiog], [fiog.row_weight, og.id]) 
|> group_by([og, fiog], [og.id, fiog.row_weight])
```

But will give the following error if run as a preload. If run as a standard query it does retrieve the right `OptionGroups`.

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42803 (grouping_error): column "f2.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

In the first example, it looks like it need a filter by `food_item_id`, but the only way to do that is using [function in preload](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-functions).

```
fn food_items_ids ->
  OptionGroup
  |> join(:inner, [og], fiog in Ketchup.FoodItemOptionGroup,
      og.id == fiog.option_group_id and fiog.food_item_id in ^food_items_ids)
  |> order_by([og, fiog], [fiog.row_weight, og.id])
  |> Ketchup.Repo.all()
end
```

But in this scenario, what the preload will do is to only add the `OptionGroup` that have the same `id` as the `FoodItem`.

I think I'm out of options to try here, I'm thinking in probably right one query without options to select which preloads you want or not.

**EDIT**

This is the preload I'm sending to Ecto:

`GET ../endpoint1?include=option_groups`

```
[       
  option_groups: #Ecto.Query<from o in Ketchup.OptionGroup,
   join: f in Ketchup.FoodItemOptionGroup, on: o.id == f.option_group_id,
   order_by: [asc: f.row_weight, asc: o.id]>
]
```

I'm displaying here without distinct, but it distinct it will show all OptionGroups, but it will not order them because row_weight aren't available in all of them, when I just want the one with the connection with `FoodItem` that have `row_weight`.

`GET ../endpoint2?include=food_items.option_groups.food_extras`

```
[       
  food_items: #Ecto.Query<from f in Ketchup.FoodItem,
   order_by: [asc: f.row_weight, asc: f.id]>,
  food_items: [
    option_groups: #Ecto.Query<from o in Ketchup.OptionGroup,
     join: f in Ketchup.FoodItemOptionGroup, on: o.id == f.option_group_id,
     order_by: [asc: f.row_weight, asc: o.id], distinct: [asc: o.id]>
  ]
]
```

**EDIT2**

So, I end up using a query. I will be trying to implement GraphQL in the future.

```
FoodCategory
|> join(:inner, [fc], r in Restaurant, r.id == fc.restaurant_id)
|> join(:left, [fc, r], fi in Ketchup.FoodItem, fi.food_category_id == fc.id)
|> join(:left, [fc, r, fi], fiog in Ketchup.FoodItemOptionGroup, fiog.food_item_id == fi.id)
|> join(:left, [fc, r, fi, fiog], og in Ketchup.OptionGroup, og.id == fiog.option_group_id)
|> join(
  :left,
  [fc, r, fi, fiog, og],
  ogfe in Ketchup.OptionGroupFoodExtra,
  ogfe.option_group_id == og.id
)
|> join(
  :left,
  [fc, r, fi, fiog, og, ogfe],
  fe in Ketchup.FoodExtra,
  ogfe.food_extra_id == fe.id
)
|> where([fc], fc.restaurant_id == ^restaurant_id)
|> preload(
  [fc, r, fi, fiog, og, ogfe, fe],
  food_items: {fi, option_groups: {og, food_extras: fe}}
)
|> order_by([fc, r, fi, fiog, og, ogfe, fe], [fc.row_weight, fi.row_weight, fiog.row_weight])
```

Comment: Can't you use [distinct](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#distinct/3) instead of `group_by`? I think appending `|> distinct(true)` to your query would work.

Comment: @GabrielPrá, `|> distinct(true)` doesn't work. `ERROR 42P10 (invalid_column_reference): for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`. `|> distinct([og], og.id)` works, but with a weird, in one endpoint it limits to 4 option groups, in another it show them all.